# How to call function from array javascript on button click

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

i am new to javascript and run into a problem.
I have an array with functions:

```
allFunctions = () => [
  function1(),
  function2(),
  function3(),
  function4(),
  function5(),
  function6(),
  function7(),
  function8(),
  function9()
]
```

Now i want to run this function and see which function results in a 'true' value. And if so i want to reuse only that function on a button click.

So if i call allFunctions() my output will be:

```
[false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false]
```

I somehow want to re-call that function which had a true value on button click?
Can anyone help me out or at least get me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend you to place the function names without parentheses (the function objects) into an array, iterate over it, save the indices if the result is true, and call the saved indices later.

Comment: This approach indeed worked out for me! I made a new array without parentheses, got the index and called the right function with the index i obtained.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an array of functions without invoking them (invoking them will create an array of results). Now you can use the array, with `Array.find()` (to get the 1st function that returns `true`) or `Array.find()` (to get all functions that return `true`):

```js
const fnFalse = () => false
const fnTrue = () => true

const allFunctions = [fnFalse, fnFalse, fnFalse, fnFalse, fnFalse, fnTrue, fnFalse, fnFalse, fnFalse]

const trueFn = allFunctions.find(fn => fn())

console.log(trueFn.name, trueFn())
```

You can do the same thing with the array you produced with `allFunctions` using `Array.indexOf`:

```js
const fnFalse = () => false
const fnTrue = () => true

const fns = [fnFalse, fnFalse, fnFalse, fnFalse, fnFalse, fnTrue, fnFalse, fnFalse, fnFalse]

const allFunctions = () => [fnFalse(), fnFalse(), fnFalse(), fnFalse(), fnFalse(),  fnTrue(), fnFalse(), fnFalse(), fnFalse()]

const trueFn = fns[allFunctions().indexOf(true)]

console.log(trueFn.name, trueFn())
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple implementation if I got you correctly. Considering two buttons.

```
<button type="button" id="find">Find</button>
<button type="button" id="search">Search</button>
```

and JS

```
var functions = {
    find: function() { alert("finding..."); },
    search: function() { console.log("searching..."); }
};
document.getElementById ("find")
    .addEventListener ("click", handleClick);
document.getElementById ("search")
    .addEventListener ("click", handleClick);

function handleClick(event) {
    functions[event.target.id]();
}
```

You can add more logic to it.

example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uq2g7z83/2/)